# Compile all java files in a directory and also include those in deeper directories

Tags: java, javac

I'm using `javac mypackage/*.java` but I want it to also include `.java` files that are in folders that are in the mypackage folder, and folders within those folders, etc.

How can I do this?

Comment: why don't you use IDE to compile? If not you can make bat-file where you recursively traverse directories or hard-code and compile all files in every.

Comment: I'm using the terminal through ssh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On a Unix-like OS, `find ./mypackage -name '*.java' | xargs javac` should sort you.

Comment: in windows ?!~ please

Answer (score 1):

You may also create an ant or maven script to accomplish the same thing. These scripts will provide you a more manageable way to build and deploy the project.
For details on ant see:
http://ant.apache.org/ for ant and http://maven.apache.org/guides/ for maven scripts.

Hope this helps.